# Networkx and graphviz layout placing nodes in same place

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I'm using the networkx library to do some work with graphs and using matplotlib for visualising.

The problem I'm having is that the nodes are getting placed over each other.
I am using my own classes for the nodes - a simplified, runnable version shown here:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

class MyCustomNode(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

def __str__(self):
    return "val: " + self.value


graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edge(MyCustomNode('a'), MyCustomNode('b'))

labels = {}
for node in graph.nodes():
    labels[node] = str(node)

pos = nx.graphviz_layout(graph)
nx.draw(graph, pos, node_color='red', node_size=3000)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos, labels, font_size=8, font_color='white')
plt.show()
```

[image: This is what displays with the code above]

What I've found is that the behaviour seems to what gets returned in the __str__ method.
If I change the __str__ method to something where the **starting** is unique, it lays out as expected:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.value
```

[image]

Can't tell if this is the expected behaviour, or I'm doing something wrong, or this is a bug.
Advice appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete, working example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's not the expected behavior (at least to me), but I suspect that finding the issue will require seeing more of the code you've developed.  Can you create a very simple graph that shows this?

Comment: Added a complete example, @Joel :)

Comment: Have you tried it without the `:` in the name?

Comment: Woah what, removing the colon worked. That was not expected, any idea why that is related? edit: if i return `":" + self.value` it works fine, same story if i return `self.value + "tag:"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't find an authoritative reference at the moment, here's what's going on:

Graphviz has some restrictions on what characters can appear in node names.  Among the characters it cannot handle is `:`.  So when everything was passed to graphviz, I believe it interpreted it as a single node whose name was just `val` (I may be wrong).

Then when networkx got the positions back from graphviz, it resulted in all the nodes being put in the same place.

So your simplest option is to remove the colon.

Comment: Thanks.
Unfortunately, no added the quotation marks does not work. In fact it makes it non-runnable I get the error
`"val\":\" b"  [height=0.5, Expected "}" (at char 187), (line:11, col:8)`

`'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_node'`

I'm fine with removing the colons - its no biggie really in this case. Although, I do find it kind of  interesting that graphviz cares about what characters are in the node label in the first place!